# Prevent Scalatra from escaping text in html page

Tags: scala, scalatra

I have a template like the following:

```
    val outMsg = s"${outMap.mkString("<p/>\n")}"

    if (returnMode.equalsIgnoreCase("HTML")) {
      response.setContentType("text/html")
      displayPage("Keywords Query Results:",
        // <p>Query: {jsonObject.get.toString}</p>
        <p>Return:
          {outMsg}
```

Now what gets sent to browser:

```
419 iphone ( 2015-05-01 )&lt;p/&gt;
381 iphone ( 2015-05-01  Texas)&lt;p/&gt;
259 iphone ( 2015-05-01  NY)&lt;p/&gt;
148 iphone ( 2015-05-01  Tx)&lt;p/&gt;
131 iphone ( 2015-05-01  CA)&lt;p/&gt;
129 android ( 2015-05-01  TX)&lt;p/&gt;
```

How to instruct scalatra to "leave the text alone" and send it to browser as-is ?

**Update** Notice that the code above is inside **DisplayPage** - which apparently does not allow the macros/markup.  I need to understand why the sample programs even use the displayPage at all -and what a better alternative will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URLEnocding is occurring due to the xml node's, not specific to scalatra. However, I did not discover how to undo the encoding before scalatra returns the contents to the requestor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it globally:

```
<% escapeMarkup = false %>
```

Or wrap the expression:

```
some text
${unescape(outMsg)}
```

Comment: OK I am trying it out.

Comment: I have updated OP :  the code sent to displayPage can not contain the macro expansions. I need to get a handle on the flow here: the sample programs do use displayPage but then it is broken.. Will update the OP yet again after getting some self education.